# Editing files on linux server from windows

Tags: windows, linux, text-editing

I want to edit text files on Linux server from Windows, using text editor like Notepad++ or UltraEdit.

I've managed to do so using WinSCP. It can edit files remotely and offers me to choose local application to open those files.

That is exactly what I need, but when I hit ctrl-s (not every time, in about 50% cases), it waits for around 10 seconds, alerts that connection has failed, and offers me to "abort". When I click abort, it instantly reconnect and save file.

So does anybody knows any other way to edit files remotely without this annoying waiting period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Notepad++ [plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppftp/) called NppFTP allows remote editing via FTP, FTPS, FTPES and SFTP.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! However, I get this error when install NppFTP plugin: "This ANSI plugin is not compatible with your Unicode Notepad++." Each time I start notepad++ it asks me to remove that plugin (interestingly though, it seems to work fine). Any ideas with that?

Comment: Actually, problem solved. When I downloaded plugin, the archive contained NppFTP and NppFTPA. Only NppFTPA is not compatible with Unicode Notepad++, and after it got deleted, file editing still works like a charm. Thanks again!